# How find this value for $b,c,d$ are real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let $b,c,d$ are real numbers, find this value

> $$\dfrac{b+c-2\dfrac{2bd-bc-cd}{b+d-2c}}{\left(\dfrac{2bd-bc-cd}{b+d-2c}\right)^2-bc}-\dfrac{d+\dfrac{4bd-cd-3bc}{b-4c+3d}-b-c}{bc-d\dfrac{4bd-cd-3bc}{b-4c+3d}}$$

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking us to simplify the expression?

Comment: Yes,my frend @Julien,Thank you

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the first by $(b+d-2c)^2$ top and bottom and the second by $b-4c+3d$? What happened?

Comment: I used [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). There you can get a free account. I created a notebook and selected the *maxima* mode instead of *sage* (4th dropdown list)
Evaluating
`(b+c-2*((2*b*d-b*c-c*d)/(b+d-2*c)))/ (((2*b*d-b*c-c*d)/(b+d-2*c))^2-b*c)-(d+((4*b*d-c*d-3*b*c)/(b-4*c+3*d))-b-c)/(b*c-d*((4*b*d-c*d-3*b*c)/(b-4*c+3*d))),ratsimp` gives `0`. But I have no idea how to get the result calculating by hand in an efficient way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I am just a bit less lazy than you I typed this expression in Mathcad, chose “Symbolics/Simplify” and obtained 0. It is a pity – so much efforts for nothing.

Comment: "Since I am just a bit less lazy than you..." +1

Comment: What do you mean by "I am a little bit less lazy then you"? That you have access to *mathcad* because you are less lazy than @china math?